# Matlab matrix operation without loop

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have a matrix `X = [x1,y1;...;xn,yn];` and a vector `index(1,n)`. The value of index are between 1 and 5.

I want to devide X in 5 matrix X1, ..., X5 according to the index.

An example :

`X = [1,1;2,2;3,3;4,4;5,5;6,6;7,7;8,8]` and `index = [1,2,3,5,4,4,5,1]`

So, I want `X1 = [1,1;8,8], X2 = [2,2]` etc...

The condition is to not use a loop over X with a if condition in order to minimise the time of execution if there are billions of points.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a lookup function to easily access the submatrices you want:

```
X = [1,1;2,2;3,3;4,4;5,5;6,6;7,7;8,8];
index = [1,2,3,5,4,4,5,1];

Xi=@(x)X(index==x,:);
subX = arrayfun(Xi,1:5,'uniformoutput',0);
```

Notice that `arrayfun` can apply the lookup function to each index in order to store all the resulting matrices in a cell array. Then they can be accessed using:

```
subX{1}
```

Which outputs:

```
 1     1
 8     8
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use logical indexing.

```
X1=X(index==1,:); % This will pick all rows of X for which index has the value 1
X2=X(index==2,:); % and the same for X2 to X5
```

Still it might be neat to loop this. Especially if you have an index array with more values than just 5.